# Composer and multiple branches

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a git project with 2 branches:

- Master: Currently the "stable branch" but subjected to changed. Releases are tagged from there.
- Devel: A development branch for the next version. This is merged into master when we think some features from here are quite stable.

In master, I have a requirement in my `composer.json` that uses a specific version:

```
"require" : {
    "triagens/arangodb" : "1.2.1",
    "php" : ">=5.4.0"
},
```

In my devel branch, I would like to use the development version of the dependency:

```
"require" : {
    "triagens/arangodb" : "dev-devel",
    "php" : ">=5.4.0"
},
```

Effectively, when branches are switched, and `composer install` or `composer update` is run I would like to have composer update/change the dependencies to the appropriate versions.

Since `composer install --dev` does not support having a different version of a dependency in `require-dev`, I cannot set the different version in the `require-dev` section.

I would also prefer to not have a separate `composer.json` for each branch as merge would be quite painful.

If you have multiple branches and each branch uses some version of a dependency, what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can maintain multiple versions of `composer.json` under different names:

- `composer.master.json`
- `composer.dev.json`

Then when you call `composer.phar install` or `composer.phar update`, you can preface the desired composer file to use:

- `COMPOSER=composer.master.json php composer.phar update`
- `COMPOSER=composer.dev.json php composer.phar update`

See the [CLI docs](http://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer).

Comment: I like your idea, but I would like to use:

`composer.json` as master file
`composer.dev.json` for development