# Composer: manage dependencies of different branches

Tags: dependencies, branch, composer-php

I am wondering, how to manage dependencies of different branches using composer? For example the dev-master version of a bundle A needs the dev-master version of bundle B, but the dev-develop version of bundle A needs the dev-develop version of bundle B.

Comment: just update the `composer.json` file in your branches?

Comment: I found the solution from the link below :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329964/composer-and-multiple-branches

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty easy: Manage the contents of `composer.json` and `composer.lock` just like any other file. I.e. you define the dependencies of every branch independently of each other simply by your needs.

If you switch branches, a call to `composer install` will install the needed dependencies of this branch. The elegant solution would be to add a build file with phing that would execute your tests, and prior to this install the correct dependencies.