# Is there a way to load a private repo locally if it exists, otherwise use the remote repo?

Tags: php, git, composer-php

For example, here is a portion of my `composer.json`

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "git",
        "url":  "ssh://git@gitlab.domain.com/project/package.git"
    }
],
```

Now I'm working on the project locally, so I already have `package` in another folder.

Do I really need to push the changes for `package` to the remote repo, then pull it in my project repo?  Or is there a way to tell composer that this repo is also available locally?

**EDIT: Basically, how do I say "use this local repo if it exists, otherwise use this remote repo"?**

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have solved this problem but I had the same and searching/googling I found a smart solution in [Composer and multiple branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329964/composer-and-multiple-branches).

In a nutshell you can use the COMPOSER environment variable to set the composer.json filename so you can get a composer.json for development (composer.dev.json for example) and another for production (composer.pro.json). Then you can use it as follows:

```
COMPOSER=composer.dev.json php composer.phar install
```

Comment: How do you deal with the composer.lock file being different?

Comment: When you specify the composer file to use it will generate you a composer.lock with the same name. For example, if you use composer.dev.json it will generate composer.dev.lock